# Hamiltons idea to use Myer's theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from  258th page of 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres, J. Differ. Geom. 20, 237-266 (1984). [ZBL0556.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0556.53001).

I want to get the red line, assume $\gamma$ is geodesic starting at $x$ with arc length parameter $\gamma$, then 
$$
\nabla_{\dot \gamma} H=\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 0} \frac{H(\gamma)-H_{\max}}{\gamma}
$$
And 
$$
|\nabla_{\dot\gamma}H| \le |\nabla H| \le \eta^2 H_\max^2
$$
let $\gamma = \eta^{-1}H_\max^{-1}$, then 
$$
H_\max-H(\gamma) \le \eta H_\max
$$
so,
$$
H\ge(1-\eta)H_\max
$$
but for other points ,$\gamma < \eta^{-1}H_\max^{-1}$, I can't get it. How to show it? Besides, I think the above process has some wrong.

> [image]

Comment: Maybe , you should use finite covering.